# LESS compilation on Play 2 is seriously slow

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, less

LESS compilation in my fresh Play 2 install is genuinely slow. Even after placing an '_' on files that do not need direct compilation, a page refresh after a LESS edit takes ~8 seconds to complete. This is compared to a local compile using Codekit which takes less than a second.

Any suggestions on speeding up this process? Is it worth filing a bug against Play to have this looked at?

Here are details on my file sizes:
My LESS setup is very simple. _reset.less (.5k) _desktop.less (13k), _tablet.less (10k), _mobile.less (8k), _sprites.less (25k) files. An all.less (.3k) file that puts it all together. That's it. The resulting css file is 53k.

Comment: how many less files do you have? How big each?

Comment: My LESS setup is very simple. _reset.less (.5k) _desktop.less (13k), _tablet.less (10k), _mobile.less (8k), _sprites.less (25k) files. An all.less (.3k) file that puts it all together. That's it. The resulting css file is 53k.

Comment: I think there might be a way to tell Play to use the native less app instead of the interpreted one via Rhino.  But I can't find any docs on that.  :(

Comment: I've noticed this problem, too. It's bad enough that I'm considering switching to the play-sass plugin, which uses the Sass Ruby gem and the `sass` command. Either that, or I'm considering writing my own plugin that uses `lessc` (assuming I can't figure out how to do that via whatever configuration parameter James Ward mentioned... time to crawl the source, I suppose).

In any case, there's an experimental setting that may help you. See the bottom of http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.1/Assets, where it talks about the `incrementalAssetsCompilation` setting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I did a write-up of a small investigation into this problem. You can find it [here](http://brizzled.clapper.org/blog/2012/12/12/play-framework-less-vs-sass-recompilation-performance/).

Bottom line: I get faster performance by switching to Sass. It's not hard to do. Use the 
[Play-Sass](https://github.com/jlitola/play-sass) SBT plugin and, if you're using Bootstrap, use the SASS Bootstrap files from the [sass-twitter-bootstrap](https://github.com/jlong/sass-twitter-bootstrap)
project.

Precompiling your LESS files via the `lessc` command is another solution, and it's quite fast.

Assuming your project uses Bootstrap, using a precompiled Bootstrap, rather than the Bootstrap LESS files, is also a big win, because the Play LESS compiler recompiles *all* LESS files when one of them changes, and Bootstrap is rather large. But, for some of us, using a precompiled Bootstrap is inconvenient...

Using Play 2.0's Rhino-based, on-demand LESS compilation is the slowest option. Pig-slow, in fact. And ignore my comment about `incrementalAssetsCompilation`. It's documented, but it does not appear to be in the 2.0.x code base.

**EDIT** (22 May, 2013) [Jonathan Parsons](https://github.com/jmparsons/) has put together a *play-lessc* plugin that uses the `lessc` command to compile LESS files. It can dramatically decrease LESS compilation times in a Play project. See https://github.com/jmparsons/play-lessc

Answer (score 2):

This will dramatically reduce the compilation time:

```
export SBT_OPTS="$SBT_OPTS -Dsbt.jse.engineType=Node"
```

It makes Play use Node instead of Rhino when running JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

From Play Framework 2.3, you can use node.js as default JavaScript engine, which is used for less compilation, js lint, CoffeeScript etc..

Download and install node.js (https://nodejs.org) library and put

```
JsEngineKeys.engineType := JsEngineKeys.EngineType.Node
```

to build.sbt.

[Reference #1](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-js-engine/blob/master/README.md) -
[Reference #2](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Assets#Managed-assets)